# Returning a data-type from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

Basically, I'm doing some SQL Querying on a remote database, and I've been told to always run queries in a seperate thread to not bother the loop of the main application (Considering it's a real time game). I'm just getting around to adding SQL support and not running the queries on a seperate thread causes massive lag; Here's what I'm attempting to do:

```
public boolean login(final String username, final String password) {
        final AtomicBoolean value = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Connection connection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                ResultSet results = null;
                try {
                    connection = getConnection("root", "", "localhost");
                    statement = connection.createStatement();

                    results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from `db`.`accounts` WHERE `username`='"+username+"'");

                    while(results.next()) {
                        String salt = results.getString("salt");
                        String dbPass = results.getString("password");

                        String hashPass = toMD5(toMD5(salt) + toMD5(password));

                        if(hashPass.equals(dbPass)) {
                            value.set(true);
                        }
                    }

                } catch(SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        return value.get();
    }
```

However, the problem is that the value of the atomic boolean is never set before the application is returned. I'm trying to find the best way to do this without blocking the thread that I'm calling on.

Note: Well aware I should be using prepared statements here, trying to figure this out first.

Comment: Use a `Future<Boolean>` instead. Learn to use `ExecutorService` as well.

Comment: Of course, the value is not set before your method returns! It is not possible to wait for the result without blocking the calling thread (because 'waiting' is exactly what 'blocking' means)!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find the best way to do this without blocking the thread that I'm calling on.

That is impossible. If that thread needs the result, it will have to block until that result is available.

One option is to use a `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`.

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...
        // when ready, successful (maybe false otherwise)
        future.complete(true)
        ...
    }
});
```

You can then either call `future.get()` which blocks the current thread or you can register a listener which will be invoked when the result is set (in that other thread, or in the current thread if the result is already ready).

---

Instead of managing your own thread, use a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find the best way to do this without blocking the thread that I'm calling on.

What you need is a listener, that can listen for your thread to finish and then execute your code.

Let's assume that you want to return a ResultSet from your thread. First, you create your own EventObject.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class ResultSetEventObject extends EventObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6904165475135245131L;

    private ResultSet resultSet;

    public ResultSetEventObject(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        return resultSet;
    }

    public void setResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) {
        this.resultSet = resultSet;
    }

}
```

There’s nothing special about this class, other than it extends EventObject. Your constructor is defined by EventObject, but you can create any methods you want.

Second, you define an EventListener interface.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

public interface EventListener {

    public void handleEvent(ResultSetEventObject eo);

}
```

You would use the EventObject you created. You can use any method name or names that you want. This is the interface for the code that will be written as a response to the listener.

Third, you write a ListenerHandler.

```
package com.ggl.event.listener;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ResultSetListenerHandler {

    protected List<EventListener> listeners;

    public ResultSetListenerHandler() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<EventListener>();
    }

    // Add method(s) to generate a ResultSet and perform the
    // fireEvent method.

    public void addListener(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(EventListener listener) {
        for (int i = listeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            if (instance.equals(listener)) {
                listeners.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireEvent(final ResultSetEventObject eo, 
            final ResultSet resultSet) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
            final EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    eo.setResultSet(resultSet);
                    instance.handleEvent(eo);
                }

            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how you write an event listener.  In your code, you would write something like this:

```
ResultSetListenerHandler handler = new ResultSetListenerHandler();
handler.addListener(new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(ResultSetEventObject eo) {
        // Code to process the eo ResultSet goes here
    }
});
```